# Como receber dados vindos de uma store procedure no CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Crie uma store procedure no mysql.
Usando o CodeIgniter 3 já configurado para usar o driver mysqli, tentei receber os dados retornados pela SP porém não obtive êxito.

SP:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_DadosRelatorio`(IN ano INT, IN mes INT, IN retirada INT, IN produto INT, 
OUT d1 INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT 
    ifnull(sum(qtde),0) INTO d1
FROM
    saida_produto 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_saida) = ano
     and
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data_saida) = mes
    and
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM data_saida) = 1
    and tipo_retirada = retirada
    and id_produto = produto;
```

Fiz a chamada no CI 3 da seguinte forma:

```
$query = $this->db->query("call SP_DadosRelatorio(2016,1,1,1,@d1"));
```

Ao exibir o `$query->result()` obtive a seguinte mensagem:

```
> > object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)[51]   public 'conn_id' => 
>     object(mysqli)[18]
>       public 'affected_rows' => null
>       public 'client_info' => null
>       public 'client_version' => null
>       public 'connect_errno' => null
>       public 'connect_error' => null
>       public 'errno' => null
>       public 'error' => null
>       public 'error_list' => null
>       public 'field_count' => null
>       public 'host_info' => null
>       public 'info' => null
>       public 'insert_id' => null
>       public 'server_info' => null
>       public 'server_version' => null
>       public 'stat' => null
>       public 'sqlstate' => null
>       public 'protocol_version' => null
>       public 'thread_id' => null
>       public 'warning_count' => null   public 'result_id' => boolean true   public 'result_array' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty   public 'result_object' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty   public 'custom_result_object' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty   public 'current_row' => int 0   public 'num_rows' => null   public 'row_data' => null
```

Como faço para acessar o valor da @d1 que vem do banco de dados mysql via store procedure?

Comment: Nao entendi, vc quer acessar um valor que esta passando na SP?

Comment: Na verdade eu passo alguns parâmentros, depois executo uma consulta na tabela saida_produto  e armazeno o valor dentro de @d1. Mas nao consigo acessar esse valor pelo codeigniter 3

Answer (score -3):

Tenta algo do tipo:

```
$data = array('p_var1'=> $arrayCampos[1],'p_var2'$arrayCampos[2]);
$resultSet = $this->db->query("CALL procedure(?, ?, @retorno1, @retorno2, @retornoX)", $data);
```

No fim é só capturar via
`$this->db->query('select @retorno1, @retorno2')`